# getting previous mails in outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using outlook 2007 in my system. the system has got re-installed windows 7 and when I configured my outlook account the old mails were not there. what to do? any suggestion

Comment: Did you erase/reformat the whole hard drive when re-installing windows? Are your emails kept on the server or only locally? Have any backups?

Answer (score 3):

Mail is saved to `.pst` files. You should look for any files on your pc with extension `.pst` and import them into Outlook 2007 to see whether they contain the mail you are looking for. Of course, if by "re-installed windows 7" you mean the hard drive was formatted, you better have a backup.

If you are using an IMAP account (as opposed to a POP3 which is not as largely used today as it once was), mail is stored on the server so it should still be there after an OS reinstall on the client. I believe the same is true for Exchange accounts.